# Set label value dynamically in a table cell

Tags: ios, swift, label, tableview, nsdictionary

hello I am having a very weird problem in my code and I don't know whats actually going on here.

I have `label` set in my view controller and when I set the value like this

```
cell.totalTripsLabel.text = "55"
```

It works.

But If I try to set value from dictionary,

```
cell.totalTripsLabel.text = self.dict["totalTrips"]! as? String
```

It doesn't work at all and nothing  displays on ViewController.

If I print the value like this

```
print(self.dict["totalTrips"]!)
```

It successfully prints the integer value

But If I do this

```
print(self.dict["totalTrips"]! as? String)
```

It prints `nil`

So I figure out by casting a value to string, it prints nil. So question is how I can set value in label which accepts string value

Dictionary result is like this

```
{
    totalTrips = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
cell.totalTripsLabel.text = String(self.dict["totalTrips"]!)
```

Comment: @Ashish Kakkad: as Anbu answered,you are casting the value of self.dict["totalTrips"] as String,so if it has value Int in it,it will be casted as String and set to the text property of UILabel

here is the sample code,

var str = "Hello, playground"
let a : Int = 5
str = String (a)
print(str) //prints 5

hope it helps..

Comment: @DroidGEEK -- Tanx bro, in before In my answer I made the one mistake , like `cell.totalTripsLabel.text = self.dict["totalTrips"]! as? Int`, thats the reason @asish Kakkad asked this, after that I modified

Comment: @DroidGEEK Anbu is just updated the answer. I don't have queries. Just see the edited answer.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Yes. (Y)